# Why doesn't the record get saved in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am using `sqlite` for the first time. I used Xammp before. Now I have a scene here. Each time I run the code below, records don't just get appended at the end of the table rather the table is created new and thus it's working just like a console.

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

db.execute('drop table if exists test')
db.execute('create table test (t1 text,i1 text)')
db.execute('insert into test (t1, i1) values (?, ?)',('xyzs','51'))
cursor = db.execute('select * from test')

for row in cursor:
    print(row['t1'],row['i1'])
```

Comment: what should i do then? @user2864740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to execute commands on a *cursor* and not the connection itself. Second, you need to commit your transactions:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cur = db.cursor() # getting a cursor

cur.execute('drop table if exists test')
cur.execute('create table test (t1 text,i1 text)')
db.commit() # commit the transaction, note commits are done
            # at the connection, not on the cursor

cur.execute('insert into test (t1, i1) values (?, ?)',('xyzs','51'))
db.commit()

cursor = cur.execute('select * from test')

for row in cursor:
    print(row['t1'],row['i1'])
```

Please have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). This will help you once you start working with other databases in Python because they all follow the same API.

Comment: You can call `execute` on the connection (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute)

Comment: @IsmailBadawi its not compliant with the DB-API, its a non-standard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This line drops the old table:

```
db.execute('drop table if exists test')
```

And this one creates a new table:

```
db.execute('create table test (t1 text,i1 text)')
```

That should explain your problem. Remove these two lines and you'll be fine - But create the table first *separately*.

Comment: Exactly the same problem?